# Regex double new line

Tags: java, regex

What I want to do is to take the left and right parts of double line.
Example

```
LEFT_PART\r\n\r\nRIGHT_PART
```

Left and right part can be anything but they will not contain double new line.
What I'm doing is not working (doesn't match the string I give it). This is what I've done so far.

```
^(.*)[\r\r|\n\n|\r\n\r\n]{1,1}(.*)$
```

It can start with anything, followed by exactly one double-new line, followed by anything.
I group the right and left because I need to use them aftewards.

EDIT
I use OR to cover all three types of new-line

Comment: You never need {1,1}. It can be shortened to {1} but is not needed either, because that is default. In your case it doesn't work either, because .* before and .* after allow more newlines again.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the default behavior. I don't care about the new lines before or after the double-new line. In the string I want to parse the double-new line appears only once, so it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets are used for character class and not grouping. Try using parens:

```
^(.*)(\r\r|\n\n|\r\n\r\n)(.*)$
```

And to avoid capturing the double newlines;

```
^(.*)(?:\r\r|\n\n|\r\n\r\n)(.*)$
```

The `{1,1}` is also redundant. I removed it.

Comment: I accept this answer because you provided the solution and pointed out the problem with the quantifier. Thnx again.

Comment: `^(\r\r|\n\n|\r\n\r\n)$`

This actually works too. That's if you don't want to select any other character.

Comment: @Vixson Hmm not quite? This one only gets the double lines, whilst the question asked for the parts before and after the double lines, so maybe you are solving a different problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you have used a character class, which matches just a single character. You should use parenthesis. Also, you can simplify your regex by using `{n}` quantifier. To match `\r\r`, use `\r{2}`:

```
^(.*)(?:\r|\n|\r\n){2}(.*)$
```

Apart from that, I would rather get the line separator for my system using:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String regex = "^(.*)" + Pattern.quote(lineSeparator) + "{2}(.*)$
```

Comment: I'm receiving the message via a tcp socket. If the system that sends me the message won't I receive \r\r? And since I'm running on windows the line separator will be \r\n and it won't match. Am I correct? Of course I didn't mention the source of my message so your idea is valid.

Comment: There is a problem with using the quantifier here (the first regex only), it will match `A\r\nB` as well, which is seen as a single newline.

Comment: Yes you are right. You already answered my question so it's accepted and upvoted, but would you mind explaining the quantifier problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I changed the accepted answer. Jerry provided an answer too and he pointed out the problem with the quantifier. Thank you Rohit for your help.

Comment: @alkis Using `(?:\r|\n|\r\n){2}`, this allows `\r\r`, `\n\n`, `\r\n\r\n`, but also `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\r\n\n`, `\r\r\n`, etc, among which you can match a single line as well (sorry for taking some time to reply :s)

Comment: What are you talking about. It's free help. You can take as much time as you need. Thank you very much, this clears out my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?m)^(.*)$[\r\n]{1,2}^$[\r\n]{1,2}^(.*)$
```

The switch `(?m)` has the effect that caret and dollar match after and before newlines for the remainder of the regular expression

Here's a [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL7xA5) of this regex working.

Comment: Will this cover all three types of new line?

Comment: @alkis Yes, but I think this throws an error because of the `+{2}` (and if this doesn't throw and error, it'll allow more than 2 newlines as well).

Comment: @alkis I've fixed it up (finally!). Click the link to see it working.

Comment: @Jerry fyi I've fixed it up. Click the link to see it working.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. I don't have the energy to test it thoroughly right now, but it seems to work fine (I didn't know about the m identifier so I learned something new too).

Comment: Hmm, not sure. From the OP, it seems that the newlines can come either in `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`, and in the first case, it will be matching from 2 newlines to 4 (4 lines from `\n\n\n\n`).

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
^(.*)(?:(\r|\r?\n){2})(.*)$
```